# Detect if user "deselects" marker on google map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm looking for a way to detect when a marker on Google map is deselected. I have a Sliding drawer, where the handle is invisible until the user clicks on the marker, and I want to make it invisible again once the marker is "deselected". I've tried with `marker.isInfoWindowShown()` but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: `Deselected` means ?  How do you do that?

Comment: When the user clicks on the map, and hides the infowindow that i shown when the marker is clicked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no event for info window disappearance, but you may work it around using

```
map.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() { ... });
```

and a couple of other "events" that make info window disappear. If you use `marker.remove()` or `marker.setVisible(false)`, they also make info window disappear when called on a marker that shows info window.

You will have to save `markerShowingInfoWindow` reference (probably from `OnMarkerClickListener` or `InfoWindowAdapter`).

Comment: i think he just wants the InfoWindow to vanish. not the whole marker.

Comment: @bofredo I think he want to know when info window vanishes. Making it vanish is simple: `marker.hideInfoWindow()`.

Comment: @MaciejGórski Thanks, this is what I wanted. I don't know why I didn't think of it myself, I guess sometimes your brain takes a break :)

Answer (score 1):

**This is useful only when the marker has an Info Window**. When the Info Window appears on marker click and closes when clicking outside the marker. You can detect that event in the map.

```
// Detect when Marker's Info Window is closed
    googleMap.setOnInfoWindowCloseListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowCloseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClose(Marker marker) {
            // Do whatever you want to do here...
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you have already selected the answer but the selected one doesn't do what you need it too.

I'm also busy with a application that uses markers and have a view that gets switched when a  user selects and deselects a marker.

This is just a simple work around.

```
 mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng)
                {
                    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker)
                        {
                            //Code for on marker click goes here
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                    //Code for marker deselect goes here
                }
            });
```

This is using two on click listeners, This way you should be able to switch the visibility depending on what the user clicks.