# Is there a way to "listen" for closing of infoWindow from google maps API?

Tags: android, google-maps

Elaboration: I am making an app which uses the google maps API. like regular when a marker is pressed a informationWindow is shown and it starts to listen for clicks on that window as shown below.

```
mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            fm.beginTransaction()
                    .setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out)
                    .add(android.R.id.content,toolBar)
                    .show(toolBar)
                    .commit();

        }
    });
```

As you can see in the code when the informationWindow is pressed a fragment is shown called toolbar and this works as intended.

The problem i face now is to hide that toolbar when the informationWindow is hidden/closed. As of right now when i press the informationWindow; the toolbar is shown but when i close the informationWindow/press else where on the map the fragment stays in place.

Is there any way to listen for a closing informationWindow or is there another way i can go to hide the fragment?

Comment: Please check out this question/answer, maybe it will help you: [infoWindow (Google Maps) catching an event of closing the window](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18756625/2610837)

Comment: That is kind if how i solved my problem. I made sure to run my code that should run when an info window closed if my fragment was showing on the screen. @fitch496

Answer (score 1):

I think this listener is what you are looking for:

To be notified when the info window closes, use an [OnInfoWindowCloseListener](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/infowindows#info_window_events), which you can set by calling

```
GoogleMap.setOnInfoWindowCloseListener(OnInfoWindowCloseListener).
```

You will receive an onInfoWindowClose(Marker) callback.

Answer (score 0):

```
private class MyMarkerClickListener implements OnMarkerClickListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        if (marker.isInfoWindowShown()) {
        // do whatever you want.
    }
}
```

You can check whether the `InfoWindow` is visible or not on marker click

Comment: This would only trigger when a maker is clicked and i want something to trigger when the infowindow is closed. Kind of like a stateChangeListener for the infoWindow.

Comment: I think there is no listener of the kind you are mentioning.@snyggt